# How to track how many times an email was opened in amazon SES through API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

How will i track how many times  email sent through Amazon SES was opened ?Is there any API i will need to consider?I figured out the complain and bounce myself and i figured out we can associate SES with SNS but i need the click rate too.Please assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Introduces click and open tracking a few months back -

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/open-and-click-tracking-have-arrived/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. SES, like any Internet mail sending system, has no idea whether a message is ever opened. It can't even be certain a message was delivered. People who want to know when a message is opened embed image links (often to invisible images) and track how often those images are fetched from their web server.

And even that doesn't work for users who configure their email program to not fetch images.

Comment: Actually SendGrid, for example, have relationships in place with various email providers to report delivery, spam reports and opens (though the latter is still using an image).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using SendGrid. Is not 100% accurate but it's something :)

Sendgrid will post you a JSON message for all the mailing events (open, delivered, bounced, spam).